# ClassNotFoundException while running Kafka hadoop-consumer

Tags: hadoop-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I'm new to Kafka and I'm test on hortonworks sanbox 2.3. I'm following kafka tutorial at 
https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/tree/master/contrib/hadoop-consumer.

When running ./run-class.sh kafka.etl.impl.DataGenerator
 test/test.properties, I get error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
        at  sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 6 more
```

I already include all possible kafka jar in  run-class.sh but still no luck. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing jar with the class **org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration** which **is not** part of the Kafka library. It should be included in *hadoop-common-2.5.0*. You have to add this jar to the classpath.